# having issues running tkinter

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, tkinter

I have been trying to run simple tkinter from python in VSC via WSL and I have been having issues. The code works just fine when I am using regular Windows but when I try to run code via VSC using WSL I always receive a traceback error. I have looked through these forums but I cannot seem to find the answer. I have used sudo-apt get install python3-tk to install it via the terminal. I have tried to run the following code for a simple root window:

```
 from tkinter import *
 root = Tk()
 label = Label(root, text="I am a label widget")
 button = Button(root, text="I am a button")
 label.pack()
 button.pack()
 root.mainloop()
```

However, I receive the following traceback error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/letsgo/guipractice/guii.py", line 3, in 
root = Tk()
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinger_init_.py", line 2270, in *init*
self.tik = >tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactove, wantobjects, useTk,
, sync, use)
_tkinger.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

I am not sure what is going on. I know that I have Tkinter properly installed because I have checked for the version that I currently have via the terminal and it has shown 8.6. When I run from tkinter import * it runs just fine.

Help would be appreciate; thank you.

Comment: What Windows version are you running?

Comment: Note that spaces are critical.  Your example starts each line with a space, which causes problems.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @ NotTheDr01ds I believe Windows 10. @ ubfab1 I do not have spaces in the actual lines in code on VSC.